# issue with date between c# and sql converting

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

so i have a string "09/15/2014" and in c# it converts it to date:

```
DateTime from = Convert.ToDateTime(fromdate);
```

this outputs "9/15/2014" and when I send it over to sql I get this:

```
select convert(varchar, '9/1/2014 12:00:00 AM', 101)
```

which doesn't work for me because I need to keep any leading zero's.

help?

Comment: Query parameters with the appropriate datatype will ensure your data is stored properly.  If you want to format it with convert, use a different style.  This page probably has the one you want.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score -3, accepted):

SQL queries use a date and time format which goes like this:

```
2014-09-15
```

That's year-month-day. As per the comments below, this may be different depending on the collation you have on your database (see Scott's comment for a more accurate way to describe this and get dates into this format).

DateTime's ToString method has an overload which takes a formatting string. So you can pass the format you want the string to be output to. Try it like this:

```
string queryDate = from.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

And see what you get. Use that on your query.

But if you really want this done right, use parameters. Like:

```
SqlCommand command = new Command(connection, "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE someDate = @date");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", from);
// where "from" is your DateTime variable from the code you've shown.
```

This will save you the trouble of DateTime to String conversions.

Comment: SQL Server absolutely does NOT use a date and time format like that. Internally dates are stored as 2 integers. The first integer is the number of dates before or after the base date (1900/01/01). The second integer stores the number of clock ticks after midnight, each tick is 1/300 of a second.

Comment: @DavidG sorry, I didn't know you did your queries like "WHERE someDate < 12321 3463" instead of using human readable dates.

Comment: My point is that dates in SQL Server don't have a format as people would assume and didn't want you to propagate that error.

Comment: @Renan The parsing of that is entirely dependent on culture you set in the collation you set when you installed the server. The only way to be ***guaranteed*** that it is parsed as `yyyy-mm-dd` is do do [`CONVERT(datetime, '2014-09-15', 102)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Minus 1.  The opening paragraph is simply incorrect.  The subsequent comment has nothing to do with how dates are stored in sql server.

Comment: I also am going to give a -1 until you fix your code example, `command.Parameters.add(from);` is not valid code. `command.Parameters.Add(from);` could be valid code but is most definitely **NOT** [the overload of `Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the OP would need to use. He should either use `Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = from;` or use `AddWithValue("@date", from);`

Comment: @Renan - The point is it should be more like `WHERE someDate < @SomeDateParameter`. Format should never enter into the conversation in the first place, because the value is passed to Sql server from the client as a DateTime, and not a string, and the exact format of the DateTime is left for Sql Server and .Net to decide rather than for you or I to choose. The only time format matters is if you're hard-coding a date into a query, which is not the case here.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: actually, with `DATETIME`, you would have to use `YYYYMMDD` (**without** any dashes!) - the format *with dashes* doesn't work for e.g. German, French etc. languages......

Answer (score 3):

If you're worried about the string formats for dates with Sql Server, you're doing it wrong. As a comment to another answer indicates, SQL Server internally stores all dates in a machine-optimized numeric format that is not easily human-readable. It only converts them to a human-understandable format for output in your developer tools.

When sending dates to Sql Server, always use query parameters. In fact, when sending *any* data, of any type, to Sql Server in an SQL statement, **always use query parameters**. Anything else will not only result in formatting issues like your problem here, but will also leave you crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. If you find yourself using string manipulation to include data of any type into an SQL string from client code, step away from the keyboard and go ask a real programmer how to do it right. If that sounds insulting, it's because it's so hard to understate the importance of this issue and the need to take it seriously.

When retrieving dates from Sql Server, most of the time you should just select the datetime field. Let client code worry about how to format it. Do you want leading zeros? Great! The Sql Datetime column will at some point be available in C# as a .Net DateTime value, and you can use the DateTime's .ToString() method or other formatting option to convert the value to whatever you want, *at the client.*